# Use user input in Android Application

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a project where there is a editText field and user will give his phone number as input. There is an imagebutton. After taping it a phone call will occur to that number. But I couldn't use the user input in the 
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:XXXXXXXXXXX"));

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.dolphin.phonecall;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private ImageButton button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iButtonCall);

        // add PhoneStateListener
        PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        // add button listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                //below I want to use user given phone number
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:XXXXXXXXXXX"));
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //monitor phone call activities

    public class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

        String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
                // phone ringing
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                // active
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

                isPhoneCalling = true;
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                // run when class initial and phone call ended,
                // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

                if (isPhoneCalling) {

                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                    // restart app
                    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                    getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    context.startActivity(i);

                    isPhoneCalling = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never referred your editText at all.

```
EditText userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EDIT_TEXT_ID);
String phoneNumber = userInput.getText();
```

and replace the `XXXXX` with `phoneNumber`

Edit: Another suggestion is to replace `XXXX..` with `((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EDIT_TEXT_ID)).getText()`

Comment: @sphoenix no problem. Happy to help.